# count word occurrence in a sentence

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to count word occurrence from a sentence (String) and i am using the below command but it not printing the correct count.

$2 = word to search
$1 = sentence

```
grep -io $2 $1 | wc -l
```

Comment: You have to quote your variables, `"$2"` and `"$1"`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Then you have to show your exact commands, the actual sentence, the actual word, and the input and output.

Comment: grep -io "$2" "$1" | wc -l

Comment: sh count_word.sh "Python is processed at runtime by the interpreter. You do not need to compile your program before executing it. This is similar to PERL and PHP." the

Comment: If it's relevant to your question, ADD IT TO THE QUESTION.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to add to it.

Comment: No sure if $1 is a string or a file but grep is a command to look in files. I don't see how it can work on strings. It would word if $1 is a file name for example

Comment: @hackela You could use a here string: `grep 'pattern' <<< 'Sentence containing the pattern'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, first check if `$1` is a file or a string, then use the appropriate `grep` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -f "$1" ]]; then
    grep -io $2 "$1" | wc -l       # If $1 is a file
else
    grep -io $2 <<< "$1" | wc -l   # If $1 is a string
fi
```